# ajax request returns "error 500", php script still working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, timeout

A thing is, a user clicks a button, it starts an AJAX request (not so important).
This ajax request calls a php script, which downloads and subsequently uploads a large file (php script should run probably 4 minutes); and naturally, a user "waits" for ajax response to tell him everything is all right.

However, after 130 seconds, this ajax request returns a response with a status code "500 Internal server error". 
However, no. 2; in the backend, the php script is still running ( i know that from the log records, which it creates).

Where can be problem?

- max_execution_time does not affect it, since php script is still running
- on localhost, everything is all right, this happens only on our production server
- memory_limit does not affect it, (php script still running)
- jquery ajax timeout does not affect it (by default, there is no timeout, i also set timeout 300 seconds, but no effect :(  )

i am welcome to any ideas, how to resolve this

**EDIT:**
caused by fastCGI idle timeout

Comment: I would change the pattern you're using, if possible. Having a request open for so long is not a great idea.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to look at fastCGI timeouts. Oddly, my server was timing out around 800~900 seconds even though the FastCGI timeouts (Activity and Request) were set to 600 seconds. For me, raising the Request Timeout value fixed the issue with my long PHP script sitting in a loop waiting for another process to finish.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add error function also in your ajax request?

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "yourpublicfunction",
   success: function(response){},
   error: function(response){
      console.log(response.responseText);
   }
});
```

so that you can see in the browser console log what your web method returns,